# Spring configuration for dependency injection

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, struts2

I'm learning spring dependency injection with Struts2, beased on a web project. In my example, I created a **zoo** having animals. Animal will talk if injection is succeed. E.g. in the console, we will see dog's talk :

```
Wowowo ฅ^•ﻌ•^ฅ
```

However, if injection failed, then we'll see :

```
zooService bean has not been injected.
```

Here's the architecture of my application :

[image: application architecture]

- `com.zoo.controller.ZooController` is the controller for receiving web actions.
- `com.zoo.service.ZooService` is the interface for animal's talk
- `com.zoo.service.ZooServiceForDog` is the implementation for dog's talk

### Problem

Up to the step, everything is OK. And the dependency injection is handled by Spring using an XML file called `applicationContext.xml`. However, I've 2 types of configuration for this file, the first one **Config 1** works but the second **Config 2** doesn't.

**Injection succeed** using config 1.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

  <bean id="zooService" class="com.zoo.service.ZooServiceForDog" />

</beans>
```

**Injection failed** using config 2.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

  <bean id="zooController" class="com.zoo.controller.ZooController">
    <property name="zooService" ref="zooServiceBean" />
  </bean>
  <bean id="zooServiceBean" class="com.zoo.service.ZooServiceForDog" />

</beans>
```

Can somebody explain why the **Config 2** cannot work ?

---

Here're other codes that might be helpful to the issue :

Class `com.zoo.controller.ZooController`:

```
package com.zoo.controller;

import com.zoo.service.ZooService;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class ZooController extends ActionSupport {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private ZooService zooService;

    public String live () {
        if (zooService != null) {
            zooService.talk();
        } else {
            System.out.println("zooService bean has not been injected.");
        }
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public ZooService getZooService() {
        return zooService;
    }

    public void setZooService(ZooService zooService) {
        this.zooService = zooService;
    }
}
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34063506/1654265.
Mincong, since you're learning, IF Spring has been chosen by you (and not imposed by your company's standards), take a look at [**Java EE** standard dependency injection, **CDI**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35358961/1654265) (in Struts2 achieved with the [Struts2-CDI-plugin](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28808488/1654265)), it helps a lot

Comment: If you have found a solution to your problem then answer yourself and accept your answer.

Comment: @AleksandrM, ma answer is inspired by the idea of Roman. And he spent many times to explain his response. So I prefer to keep his answer :) And I'll look at your proposition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It cannot work because the scope of the `zooController` is singleton. You should make the scope `prototype`.

```xml
<bean id="zooController" class="com.zoo.controller.ZooController" scope="prototype" >
   <property name="zooService" ref="zooServiceBean" />
</bean>
```

The dependency management is defined by the container:

> If your actions managed by Struts container, then Struts is creating them in the `default` scope. If your actions is managed by Spring container then you need to define the scope of the action beans, because Spring by default uses `singleton` scope and if you don't want to share your action beans between user's requests you should define the corresponding scope. You can use `prototype` scope, which means a new instance is returned by the Spring each time Struts is being built an action instance.

The Struts integrates to Spring via plugin. Make sure it has

```
<constant name="struts.objectFactory" value="spring" />
```

then you can delegate actions to Spring

**References:**

- [Struts2 and Spring](https://struts.apache.org/getting-started/spring.html)
- [Spring plugin](https://struts.apache.org/getting-started/spring.html#struts-2-spring-plugin)

**EDIT:**

In your first config you declared a bean `zooService` that will be injected by Struts using `spring` object factory.

In your second config you declared two beans `zooController` and `zooServiceBean`, but you changed the name of the second bean. Then you tried to build the action bean using `spring` object factory like in the first case. And because there's no bean with name `zooService` the autowiring has been failed. Because by default Struts is configured to autowire beans from the application context by name.

Then you changed `struts.xml` and used a bean reference in the action class attribute. It means that Struts will use app context to get a bean from Spring. And because it has an explicit dependency on the second bean, it would be wired before the bean is returned.

Comment: I fellow your proposition, the scoped has been changed and constant has been added. Unfortunately, it didn't work. But when I renamed the `zooServiceBean` to `zooService`, config 2 worked without additional changes. Any idea ? Is it related to the wiring mode in spring-struts plugin ?

Comment: Struts wires beans by name.

Comment: If `zooServiceBean` is changed to `zooService`, it means the beans are still managed by struts. Actually, config 2 aims to delegate actions to spring. And the solution is: in `struts.xml`, rename the action node from `com.zoo.controller.ZooController` to `zooController` as specified in `applicationContext.xml`. So that struts can find the bean created by spring container. If you're agreed with me, could you please update your answer so that i can accept it ?