# What is the default scope on actions in struts2?

Tags: struts2

I am confused about Scope of action class in struts2 please help me to avoid confusion.

Is it Singleton or not?

Comment: Hi @vishal-gaikwad -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34051316/can-an-action-class-be-scoped-to-singleton ?

Comment: Google is your friend any next time, before you ask a question. ;)

Comment: What scope do you mean? See http://stackoverflow.com/q/17244036/573032

Comment: I mean default scope of Struts2 action.

Comment: I don't understand.....