# Struts2 - Validate error not refreshing on action tag call

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, struts-tags, struts-action

I'm currently having a problem with my setup.
I have this action tag in my JSP

```xml
<s:action name="doLogin" executeResult="true"></s:action>
```

and below is the corresponding struts.xml entry

```xml
<action name="doLogin" class="siteLoginAction">
    <result name="input">login</result>
    <result name="success">home</result>
</action>
```

The jsp is just a login div (form, textfield, label).

Now the problem is that when I'm testing the validate function

```java
@Override
public void validate() {
    String username = siteUser.getSiteUserUsername();
    String password = siteUser.getSiteUserPassword();

    if (StringUtils.isEmpty(username) || StringUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
        addFieldError("siteUser.siteUserUsername", "Invalid login");
    } else if (!siteUserService.checkLoginExists(username, password, getBlogSiteUrl())) {
        addFieldError("siteUser.siteUserPassword", "Invalid login");
    }
}
```

As you can see it works,

[image]

but it will not go away. The error message will stay there everytime I visit that page.

Is this because of the singleton default model of the Struts2 action?
I have tried @Scope("prototype") but if I use it it doesn't display the error at all

Answer (score 0):

> I have this `<s:action>` tag in my JSP

You should not use that tag, it's an old and useless technology, drop it ASAYC.

> Is this because of the singleton default model of the Struts2 action? I have tried @Scope("prototype") but if I use it it doesn't display the error at all

Actions are ThreadLocal. What you're referring to with *"default model"*   is the *default scope* (Singleton) of a Spring bean, [and hence of a Struts2 Action if managed by Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34063506/1654265). And it would be wrong, you should use `scope="prototype"` in that case, to make the Spring managed actions working correctly as ThreadLocal objects.

This question is not answerable more than this right now; just drop the `<s:action/>` tag, use `scope="prototype"` (or drop Spring, at least on actions handling) and see what happens, then if it still doesn't work, come back here and ask again: it will be easy to help you then.

Comment: I'll see what I can do about the action tag. The problem is that the JSP calling the action is unknown (can be any filename) so I had no choice but to return the result via action tag.

Comment: That's not right: why *any unknown* JSP should be able to embed a login window inside of it ? If a login is needed, just redirect the whole page to a login page (eventually storing the URL of the page you're coming from), then after a succesful login come back to it. Easier and more clean, imho

Comment: otherwise use an iframe

Comment: Or don't use the login fragment as a page, but as a reusable component that can be dropped into any page.